# Automator variable base on file name (Applescript?)

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I am trying to use *automator* to rename files based on the folder I select as the input. I want to take the folder name and if 1 of 4 phrases are found in the folder name, 1 of 4 variables would be used. I don't know **applescript** but I feel this is the way to go base on other languages I know.

Can anyone convert the following concept?

> if file name contains "USA" then
>
> var = "US"
>
> elseif file name contains "CAN_FR" then
>
> var = "CAFR"
>
> elseif file name contains "CAN_EN" then
>
> var = "CAEN"
>
> end

Much appreciation to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Finder" to set folderName to name of first item of input
    if folderName contains "USA" then
        set var to "US"
    else if folderName contains "CAN_FR" then
        set var to "CAFR"
    else if folderName contains "CAN_EN" then
        set var to "CAEN"
    else
        set var to "Not Found"
    end if

    -- insert your code here
    return var

end run
```

Comment: Perfect! Functions just the way I need it.

Comment: Option tweak needed: What would I need to add so the last else statement would bring a prompt up. I am thinking like how the ask for text option works in automator. The prompt would say "Please manually define variable" and have one input line to type in. I found a situation where this might be needed. Thanks again.